# How to resolve page is missing in angular 2 boiler?

Tags: javascript, angular

I just started learning angular 2 and cloned this repo:
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter. Just adding an extra menu option called 'list'. I have created the component and added it to the routes:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',      component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'detail', loadChildren: './+detail#DetailModule'},
  { path: 'barrel', loadChildren: './+barrel#BarrelModule'},
  { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent },
  { path: 'list', component: ListComponent}
];
```

This is the list component:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'list',
  styles: [`
  `],
  template: `
    <h1>list</h1>
    <div>
      For hot module reloading run
      <pre>npm run start:hmr</pre>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>
        patrick@AngularClass.com
      </h3>
    </div>
    <pre>this.localState = {{ localState | json }}</pre>
  `
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  public localState: any;
  constructor(
    public route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.route
      .data
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        /**
         * Your resolved data from route.
         */
        this.localState = data.yourData;
      });

    console.log('hello `List` component');
    /**
     * static data that is bundled
     * var mockData = require('assets/mock-data/mock-data.json');
     * console.log('mockData', mockData);
     * if you're working with mock data you can also use http.get('assets/mock-data/mock-data.json')
     */
    this.asyncDataWithWebpack();
  }
  private asyncDataWithWebpack() {
    /**
     * you can also async load mock data with 'es6-promise-loader'
     * you would do this if you don't want the mock-data bundled
     * remember that 'es6-promise-loader' is a promise
     */
    setTimeout(() => {

      System.import('../../assets/mock-data/mock-data.json')
        .then((json) => {
          console.log('async mockData', json);
          this.localState = json;
        });

    });
  }

}
```

For some reason I get this errormessage when I hit http://localhost:3000/#/list:

```
404 page missing
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the list route to above the ** route like below:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '',      component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'detail', loadChildren: './+detail#DetailModule'},
  { path: 'barrel', loadChildren: './+barrel#BarrelModule'},
  { path: 'list', component: ListComponent},
  { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent }
];
```

The router uses a first match wins strategy for matching routes. So, if the wildcard route ** is declared above 'list', the wild card route prevails.

Read the official router documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just rearrange the order of routes in your ***app.routes.ts*** file and it should work.

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
 { path: '',      component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
 { path: 'list', component: ListComponent},
 { path: 'detail', loadChildren: './+detail#DetailModule'},
 { path: 'barrel', loadChildren: './+barrel#BarrelModule'},
 { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent }
];
```

[image]